# How to use Sqlite with C# the visual way?

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqlite

Coming from the Delphi world, where I was used to dropping TConnections, TQueries and TDataSets on my Forms to easily connect to a SQlite database file, I'm struggling to do the same with Visual Studio and C# (which I'm trying my hands on).

I found here this image :
[image]

showing that, it is possible to use Sqlite3 "visually" and finally found the way (installed ODBC drivers for Sqlite) to achieve this result.

But I am still struggling to connect a DataGridView with a DataSource and have it fill the Grid. 
It works programmaticly though, but I'd like to do it the visual way.

Can someone show me or explain to me how (I suppose it as easy as it is with Embarcadero RAD Studio) to bind sources and destinations in order to fill the DataGridView ?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Mathias

Comment: I really have no idea if that helps, but you may want to have a look [at this](http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html)